# Dynamic hostnames with Bind9 reverse lookup

Tags: dns, bind, reverse, auto

I'm wondering how it is possible to let bind9 generate IP-based hostnames for reverse lookup zones.
For example, my ISP does this for his public IPs. 81.89.161.129 -> 81.89.161.129.suec-darcor.de

I would like to have this too in my bind for my IPv6 suffix. Google does not help me in this question.
I can't imagine that it is necessary to create zone files with all possible combinations for this purpose.

Thanks and Greetings
Marcus